# Turbo charger, charges slow,why?

Tags: 7.0-nougat

My Motorola g4 plus has turbo charger when I charge in that it takes to charge full about 4 to 6 hours.But in Moto specification it was given that it will charge to 80% in 30 minutes.

Comment: It's cable matters. Or maybe you didn't plug in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same cable that came in box? if so then it should charge fast not that fast 80% in 30 min... that's test lab results... in real life application those figures may differ... its pretty much normal.

Answer (score 0):

Can be a problem either in phone or charger or cable. It takes almost 40 minutes to charge upto 75% on turbo charge. I know it because I own it.
If this is a new device you can claim warranty and get replacement. FYI turbo charging will work until battery reaches 80% or so and after that it charges slowly. So total time to charge whole battery is 1hr 20 min in my case​.
Are you using the cable supplied with the charger?
Ps. Moto Turbo charger supports 3 modes of charging. Please read what's printed on it.